# Optimal projection to model solar shadows

Tags: coordinate-system

I would like to map the shadows of mountains from a high resolution DEM. Therefore I am wondering if there is a coordinate system which would represent the projection of the rays of the sun as straight lines in the XY plane (image 1) 
[image]

in order to easily compute the position of obstacles (image 2. 
[image: image two: shadow of the sun]

As mentioned in the comments, all light rays are parallel, so they should be represented as parallel lines on the map. I am not sure that it is not possible, so the less bad solution is welcome.

Comment: Can you provide a sketch to illustrate what you mean by "CRS which would represent a ray of the sun"?

Comment: Considering the long (infinite?) distance to the sun and the relativelly small area of interest (I guess), sun rays could be considered as straight parallel lines. Any CRS based on a *planar projection* would then preserve this parallelism.

Comment: Not directly related to the question: https://twitter.com/geo_spatialist/status/1254184243908968448 is an interesting example of using 'true' shading, compared to traditional cartographic hillshading. Blender software was used for that.

Comment: sun ray are straight lines if you done take refraction into account, and I think that refraction is mainly in the vertical plane so it does not influence the azimuth. However, not all straight line projected on a sphere will be straight lines on a planar map.